# UINavigationController Backbutton dissapeared in iOS 6.1

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I upgraded to xCode (Version 4.6 (4H127)) yesterday and suddenly one of my UIViewController doesnt show its backbutton when its pushed.

Backbutton **appears** in iPad Simulator (**6.0**).
No Backbutton in iPad Simulator **6.1**

Any ideas why?

I dont do anything in strange in my viewDidload.

//This is how I push the TableViewController.

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller
                                           animated:YES];
```

**UPDATE**
Okej so iOS 6.1 is far more nervous about not having named the RootViewController. Adding a title to my RootController helped.

Comment: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];